# Single quotes and double quotes all are used. Then what should i use?

Tags: javascript, jquery

here my script.

```
$.each(data, function (index, value) {
                j += '<a href="#" onclick="displayDetails('+data[index].name+', '+data[index].num1+', '+data[index].num2+', '+data[index].num3+')">'+data[index].name+'<a/>'+'<br/>';
            });
```

I used single quotes and double quotes. But i want to add a quotes in between

```
'+data[index].name+'
```

What quote i should add that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can escape quotes with `\`

such as: `j += "<a href=\"#\"></a>";`