# Nesting quotes in Angular expression

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In .js files triple nested quotes ("one'two"three"'") can be escaped ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27493270/single-quotes-and-double-quotes-all-are-used-then-what-should-i-use)) and in HTML this can also be achieved using character references ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039765/nesting-quotes-in-javascript-html)). I have a problem achieving this in an AngularJS expression in my template.

I need to put this:

```
{{ 'PLURAL' | translate:"{ GENDER: 'male' }":"messageformat" }}
```

Into a placeholder element:

```
<input placeholder="{{ 'PLURAL' | translate:"{ GENDER: 'male' }":"messageformat" }}">
```

How should I escape the quotes to make it work?

Comment: are you sure your translate filter needs objects wrapped in quotes? Seems very odd

Comment: you're right, the filter doesn't need it. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer would be put `{ GENDER: 'male' }` in some scope variable then do use that inside your interpolation directive expression, that will simplify your escaping more better.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-init="maleFilter = { GENDER: 'male' }">
   <input ng-attr-placeholder="{{ 'PLURAL' | translate: maleFilter : 'messageformat' }}">
<div>
```

Hope this could help you, Thanks.

Comment: Nope, prints the non-interpolated string up onto the first escape like this: {{ 'PLURAL' | translate:\

Comment: Cool stuff. Not an answer to the problem though.

Comment: @JesseBuitenhuis could you add some code, so that we can play with it & will help you find out correct answer..

Answer (score 1):

For future reference. These Angular Translate [docs](http://Angular%20Translate%20Docs:%20Pluralization) were confusing to me.

The format that works is:

```
placeholder="{{ 'PLURAL' | translate:{gender:'male'}:'messageformat' }}"
```

Comment: did you placed `placeholder` to and scope variable?

Comment: Sorry - updated my answer so it corresponds to the original question. The `placeholder` in my previous answer was bound to a scope variable.

Comment: it looks like same as that of my second suggestion in answer..only i took `{gender:'male'}` into scope variable

Comment: But the first version of your answer is incorrect - could you update and I'll mark as anwered.